# Understanding and calculating all the trading fees

Tags: market-microstructure, financial-markets, fees

I'm trying to make a simple script that calculates fees (commission, regulatory, exchange and others). Taking [Fee Table from IBKR](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=49637) as an example I have a few questions:

1. Is "Value of Aggregate Sales" the same as "Trade Value" (i.e. number of securities traded*the value of those securities)
2. With regards to [NYSE exchange fees](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=934&nhf=T), what's the difference between 'hidden' and different tapes (A,B, and C)? Aren't all securities on NYSE Tape A? Also, if I choose "Add Liquidity" does that mean that I get credited e.g. USD 0.0012 from the exchange for trading (thus partially offsetting my commission)? Lastly, what does USD 0.0012 refer to? Is that per security, per trade or what?
3. What is the difference (regarding fees) between an order and a trade? Isn't order just a (yet) unexecuted trade?
4. Is there a way to understand what category security falls into from Yahoo Finance or any other data provider? (e.g. with info() method)? Furthermore, is it possible to find out which Tier security is for HKEX or SGX without manually searching the internet?

Feel free to add anything else (including materials) that would help with understanding this.

Thank you in advance.